# Convert to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How I will save this to stored procedure? And run the stored procedure in c#?

```
string a = "Select * from EmpTable Where EmpName Like @SearchItem";

using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" "+ a +" ", myDatabaseConnection))
{
     SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchItem", "%" + textBox1.Text + "%");
}
```

Comment: You want to create a stored proc with that query and call that from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchSP
 @SearchItem nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    Select * 
    from EmpTable 
    Where EmpName Like '%' + @SearchItem + '%'

END
GO
```

Code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SearchSP", myDatabaseConnection))
{
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchItem", textBox1.Text);
     //rest of the code 
}
```

Comment: @BlackTigerX - how I will convert it to avoid sqlinjection?

Comment: @BlackTigerX :) using `Parameters` prevent SQL injection, is there is anything else, please explain, otherwise this is just meaning less comment

Answer (score 0):

What your Saying is you want the string gone and to call a stored procedure instead that has this SQL code inside?  If that's the case..

Presuming SQL server 2008 management studio..

In management studio expand your **"database"**,  Then Expand **"Programmability"**...
**Right click create new stored procedure** and delete all code inside.

then type in the following.

```
USE [YourDataBaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AnyName] 
@SearchItem as nvarchar(MAX)
AS
Select * from EmpTable Where EmpName Like @SearchItem
```

click run/execute and refresh your database, if you look in the stored proc folder you should see your new stored procedure.

Then in your (**presuming C#.Net**) code.

```
public string GetUserFinal(string _userInput)
{
    string temp = "";
    using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(Conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.your procedure name";
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchItem", _userInput);
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            myCommand.Connection = myConn;
            While (reader.read())
            {
                //populate a string? or do something else?
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

A better way would be to Strongly type all of this.  So i would create a Model of whatever you now the fields and types will be, then create a list And iterate through that list to bind from this Function.  But as you can see the basics, this should work just check the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure something like below:

```
Create Procedure dbo.Test
@SearchItem
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table WHERE EmpName LIKE '%'+@SearchItem+'%')
      SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE EmpName LIKE '%'+@SearchItem+'%'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS 'ErrorNumber', ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'ErrorMessage', ERROR_SEVERITY() AS 'ErrorSeverity', ERROR_STATE() AS 'ErrorState', ERROR_LINE() AS 'ErrorLine'
RETURN ERROR_NUMBER()
END CATCH
END
```

Now you can refer this sp in code-behind as below:

```
SqlConnection xconn=new SqlConnection(Write your connection string);
SqlCommand xcommand=new SqlCommand("Test",xconn);
xcommand.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
xcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchItem",DbType.String,txtBox1.Text);
xconn.Open();
xCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
xconn.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

this will be your stored proc, (haven't tested the code):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestStoredProc 
    @SearchItem nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select * 
    from EmpTable 
    Where EmpName Like '%' + @SearchItem + '%'

END
GO
```

Then in code side do this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("TestStoredProc", conn) { 
CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchItem",textbox.Text)}) {

}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't be `ExecuteNonQuery` since it is a query right.